# Numpy subarray given by center and radius

Tags: python, numpy, sub-array

Is there a function or more concise notation to get `b` or `bb` in the code snippet below?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
c = (1, 2)
r = 1
b = a[c[0]-r:c[0]+r, c[1]-r:c[1]+r]
bb = a[c[0]-r:c[0]+r+1, c[1]-r:c[1]+r+1]
```

The objective is to get a subarray defined by a center index `c` and radius `r` (L1-norm).

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `bb`?. It seems like a pythonic solution and how numpy is intended to work.

Comment: @mozway @Timo Imagine a higher dimensional array, e.g. 8, and all the cruft hiding intended meaning, which is `c-r:c+r`.

Comment: Not much better in my opinion, but you might consider `a[tuple(slice(i-r, i+r) for i in c)]` for higher dimensions.